# Using jQuery UI Accordion with program-generated HTML

Tags: jquery-ui

I am trying to create a JQuery UI Accordion, but with the HTML within an accordion being generated by some jQuery code.

I also have some example accordion items in the base HTML; these are working fine.

The problem is that the (sample 1)

```
$(function(){
    $("#accordion").accordion({
        event: "click hoverintent"
    });
});
```

code puts accordion-specific class, role etc. tags into the

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">Heading</a></h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Stuff
        </p>
    </div>
...
```

tags, but these are not being inserted into the HTML code I generated with jQuery.

The items above '...' are working fine.
Similar tags generated by jQuery below the '...' do not work, as they don't receive the accordion tags.

I guess the problem lies in when to call the (sample 1) code, so that it is executed *after* my HTML has been generated. At present it is in the head of my page, as with the accordion examples. I have tried it in other places, and also tried  but without success.

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0):

You need to destroy then recreate the accordion for it to be able to work with appended items.
Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/drewP/GzdwS/1/)